# Scikit Learn - How to plot probabilities

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I want to plot the models prediction probabilities.

```
plt.scatter(y_test, prediction[:,0])
plt.xlabel("True Values")
plt.ylabel("Predictions")
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

However, I get a graph like the above. Which kind of makes sense but I want to visualize the probability distribution better. Is there a way I can do this with my actual classes being 0 or 1 and predictions between between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 9):

Predicted probabilities can be utilized to visualize the model performance. True labels could be indicated using colors.

Try this example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=1, shuffle=False)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr=LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs', max_iter=10)
lr.fit(X, y)

prediction=lr.predict_proba(X)[:,1]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
plt.hist(prediction[y==0], bins=50, label='Negatives')
plt.hist(prediction[y==1], bins=50, label='Positives', alpha=0.7, color='r')
plt.xlabel('Probability of being Positive Class', fontsize=25)
plt.ylabel('Number of records in each bucket', fontsize=25)
plt.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=25, pad=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a pyplot setting that will stack the two hist categories rather than overlaying?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the values according to the true value and then plot two histgrams of the values for the two classes, for example with the following (at least if you have a numpy arrays `arr_true` and `arr_pred` this should work):

```
arr_true_0_indices = (y_test == 0.0)
arr_true_1_indices = (y_test == 1.0)

arr_pred_0 = prediction[arr_true_0_indices]
arr_pred_1 = prediction[arr_true_1_indices]

plt.hist(arr_pred_0, bins=40, label='True class 0', normed=True, histtype='step')
plt.hist(arr_pred_1, bins=40, label='True class 1', normed=True, histtype='step')
plt.xlabel('Network output')
plt.ylabel('Arbitrary units / probability')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

This should result in something like this: [image]